# Touchpad scroll gesture registered as pinch zoom in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, touchpad, gestures

When I compose a message in Outlook and scroll using my touchpad's two finger gesture up or down, often it is registered as pinch zoom gesture. This is very annoying! I like to keep my zoom level at 100% so every time this happens I have to actually pinch zoom the compose window to go back to 100%.

This doesn't happen in other applications. Chrome, Firefox, Edge are not that sensitive to register my scroll gesture as pinch. Is there a way to adjust Outlook's sensitivity to pinch zoom? I don't want to disable pinch zoom gesture because I like to use it when I actually need to zoom.

Laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 5510.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the touchpad driver settings?

Comment: This probably relates to Windows rather than Outlook. Are you being careful not to change the distance between the fingers?

Comment: Agree with harrymc, there's no such option to disable it in Outlook.

Comment: @Endy Tjahjono: Do you see this *only* when composing, or sometimes when attempting to scroll the reading pane?  When you see it during composition, is it in a reply draft that opens in the reading pane as opposed to popping out to a new window?  There is a similar issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-2019-2-finger-panning-on-touchpad-changes/5eb752e7-eebd-4819-bb19-3f4f51156c71), but only when reading and scrolling messages in the reading pane.

Comment: @user2153235 thanks for the info, but I have given up and disabled the pinch zoom gesture. Luckily I can still press CTRL to zoom in and out in some applications.

Comment: @Endy Tjahjono: OK, thanks for the update